# How to change width of bars in Blazorise Barchart?

Tags: c#, bar-chart, blazor, blazorise

I have used bar chart using Blazorise.Charts in my program to draw a bar chart. Default width is automatically set but I need to change the default width of bars in barchart. So, how can we achieve this in blazor?

Here's how my code looks like,

```
 <BarChart @ref="uniqueIssueByVersionBarChart" TItem="int" OptionsJsonString="@myStackedOptions" />
```

Comment: Post your code. Blazor produces HTML, which is styled through CSS. Have you tried changing the styles used by your chart, or specifying a new style?

Comment: From the docs, it looks like Blazorise Charts uses [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) You can check the library's documentation for styling examples

Answer (score 0):

As said in the commants under your question the underlying library to draw the charts appears to be chart.js. In the documentation you can see that the dataset has a property `barThickness` which you can set to a custom value

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration